# How might I force the desktop to load for a specific (master/admin) user?

Tags: startup

After noticing that /dev/sda7 was 100% used, because Transmission told me there was no space to do what I wanted to do, I deleted a number of files from my downloads folder, and shut down my computer. The next time I started up, I entered my password at the login screen, as I always do, and instead of loading the desktop, only a blue screen loaded. It appeared as if more might eventually load -- maybe it just takes more time because of this directory that's 100% full. I wandered away for about 15 mins. while waiting for the desktop to load, and when I returned, the desktop was still plain blue, without any menu, dock, icons, or toolbar.

Interestingly, I am able to login to the same partition, as a guest user.

How might I log into the admin. account, and force the desktop to load properly?

Failing that, is there a way to sign in as guest, and then access and edit files found in /dev/sda7?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> How might I log into the admin. account, and force the desktop to load properly?

Control-alt-f1 (f2 through f6 will do the same; if you do not get a login there is also something wrong with your graphics card ;) ) will give you a text based login. Log in with your admin account and check the disks with

```
df -H
```

It will list all partitions and a percentages used. If any of the partitions are on 100% see if you can remove some stuff on the directory associated to that partition.

The are some options you can do after that:

```
sudo reboot
```

to reboot. Or ...

```
exit
```

to quit this sesssion and then control-alt-f7 gets you back to the desktop.

---

> and force the desktop to load properly?

Easiest would be to reboot after you are done doing maintenance. This will reset everything and should allow you to login. If it does not it would also be adviced to login to console (ie. control-alt-f1) and check the log files in `/var/log/` (needs admin access). A command to use on these text files is `tail -n 100 {logfile}` (shows the last 100 lines in a file).